# read socket raise errno 9 randomly

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, errno

I have a client/server setup communicating over tcp sockets.
Functional wise works very nice except i got an errno 9 , randomly but quite often, when reading the socket on the server side.
According to docs and discussions i could find, errno is raised when read operation is done for a socket which is locally closed.
I'm pretty sure i'm not closing the socket in the reading loop on server side. The socket is closed only by client after message is sent.
Here is the reading loop on server side

```
void *client_listener_thread(void *args)
    {
    struct th_params *param = (void  *) args;
    int sockfd, n, client_pos;
    message_t messageR;
    char logbuf[256], buf[256];
    sockfd = param->socket;
    while(1)
        {
        n = read(sockfd, &messageR, sizeof(message_t));
        if (n < 0)
            {
            sprintf(logbuf, "cmd_thread: ERROR reading from socket errno=%d sock=%d thread=%x", errno, sockfd, (uint32_t)(param->client_listener));
            logwts(logbuf);
            break;
            }
        else if(n == 0)
            {
            sprintf(logbuf, "cmd_thread: socket closed by remote peer 2 %x", (uint32_t)(param->client_listener));
            logwts(logbuf);
            break;
            }
        else
            {
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &messageR.header.sender_ip, buf, 255);
            sprintf(logbuf, "cmd_thread:URC Message: ID = %d sender = %s\n", messageR.header.messageID, buf);
            logwts(logbuf);

// process message
            switch(messageR.header.messageID)
                {
                case IDENT_ACK:
                    ...
                    sprintf(logbuf, "New client registered on socket %d  %d / %s:%d", sockfd, client_pos, buf, messageR.header.sender_port);
                    logwts(logbuf);
                    break;
                ...
                
                default:
                    sprintf(logbuf, "cmd_thread:unprocessed message %d", messageR.header.messageID);
                    logwts(logbuf);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    if(sockfd)
        close(sockfd);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
```

On client side, it is just open the socket, send the message, close the socket.
When running, on server side, i got "New client registered ..." message for the first read and on the second read i got either the expected "socket closed by remote peer..." message or unexpected "ERROR reading from socket.." with errno = 9
As i said functional has no problem, no message lost, the message is received and processed. I could ignore the error but i'm tring to understand it first.

Comment: errno 9 is `EBADF` and means "bad file descriptor". I suggest using perror() (or strerror()) to replace the errno code with a more userfriendly message.
I think the `read()` gets called with a wrong `sockfd`

Comment: thx @Sinic for the comment! i was looking into the same potential issue but the logs show the same socket no.
`[12/31/21 - 10:45:42.552] tcp_server:New cmd thread 0 **5** 12fa5700
[12/31/21 - 10:45:42.553] cmd_thread:URC Message: ID = 2 sender = 192.168.0.152
[12/31/21 - 10:45:42.553] New client registered on socket **5**  0 / 192.168.0.152:8001
[12/31/21 - 10:45:42.553] cmd_thread: ERROR reading from socket errno=9 sock=**5** thread=12fa5700`

Comment: what does the `close()` call return respectively what value is `errno` afterwards?
I assume `close()` returns -1 and errno still is 9.
That would mean, that the descriptor (in this case 5) is getting closed elsewhere

Comment: Yes that's, true close() returns -1 and errno is still 9, but i'm trying since 2 weeks now to figure out where else in the code the socket is closed and found nothing :(. Is there a way to register a catch for socket operations?

Comment: I would use printf outputs before every `close()` call in the code printing the descriptor that ist getting closed. If that does not work and you are on a linux machine, you can use `strace` to check for all system calls made by the application.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to strace could find the culprit.
A race condition between threads. One thread was closing the socket while the other thread was still using it. A mutex did the job.
Completely true @Sinic's comment
"... that the descriptor (in this case 5) is getting closed elsewhere..."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).